# Is there some trick that would allow me to pass stream manipulators to a variadic template function?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, variadic-templates

I've been trying to write a thread-safe wrapper for std::cout and figured it's a good time to learn me some variadic templates.

[Like that.](http://i0.kym-cdn.com/photos/images/original/000/557/347/19f.gif)

Then, just when I thought I got it right, I noticed it doesn't work with std::endl.

Take this code:

```
template <typename... P>
void f(P...){}

int main()
{
    f(1,2,3,std::endl);
}
```

When you try to compile it, GCC complains in a very silly way:

```
main.cpp:18:19: error: too many arguments to function 'void f(P ...) [with P = {}]'
```

When you try that with a regular template, you get

```
main.cpp:22:13: error: no matching function for call to 'f(<unresolved overloaded function type>)'
```

which actually makes sense.

It's not a big issue for me, I can do it in some other way, but I'd really like to know if there's a way to go around that limitation.

Answer (score 15):

Instead of the explicit template arguments as suggested by Andy Prowl, I recommend template argument deduction:

```
C:\Temp>type meow.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
using namespace std;

void Print() { }

template <typename T, typename... Rest> void Print(T&& t, Rest&&... rest) {
    cout << forward<T>(t);
    Print(forward<Rest>(rest)...);
}

int main() {
    ostream& (* const narrow_endl)(ostream&) = endl;

    Print("Hello, world!", narrow_endl, "I have ", 1729, " cute fluffy kittens.",
        static_cast<ostream& (*)(ostream&)>(endl)
    );
}

C:\Temp>cl /EHsc /nologo /W4 /MTd meow.cpp
meow.cpp

C:\Temp>meow
Hello, world!
I have 1729 cute fluffy kittens.
```

N3690 13.4 [over.over] specifies the rules being used here, which go back to C++98. Basically, taking the address of an overloaded and/or templated function is ambiguous in general, but permitted in specific contexts. Initialization and static_casting are two of those contexts, because they provide sufficient type information to disambiguate. This allows template argument deduction to proceed normally.

Explicit template arguments are very tempting, but they can explode in all sorts of ways. It's unlikely that std::endl will ever be changed in a way that breaks explicit template arguments here, but I really recommend against them (except when things are specifically designed for them, like forward and make_shared).

Comment: So there's no way to write something that would allow the user to use the modifiers by their regular names, instead of things like narrow_endl?

Comment: @user697683 if you're going to write a print function wrapping an ostream, you might as well introduce wrappe functionality for formatting (i.e. don't allow use the ostream manipulators in your interface and provide alternatives). But then you'd end up with some printf implemented on top of ostream which is most likely implemented on top of C printf.

Answer (score 10):

The problem is that manipulators like `std::endl` are function templates. Therefore, you have to be explicit about which specialization of that function template you want to be passed (otherwise, no type deduction is possible).

For instance:

```
f(1, 2, 3, &std::endl<char, std::char_traits<char>>);
//                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Answer (score 2):

`template` functions are not functions, and `std::endl` is a `template` function.

You cannot pass a `template` function around.  You can, however, pass a function object which represents an overload set around.  Writing such a functor is pretty easy:

```
struct endl_overloadset {
  template<typename... Args>
  auto operator()(Args&&...args)const
    ->decltype(std::endl( std::forward<Args>(args) ) )
    { return ( std::endl( std::forward<Args>(args) ) ) };

  template<typename T,typename=typename std::enable_if<\
    std::is_same< decltype(static_cast<T>( std::endl )), T >::value\
  >::type>\
  operator T() const { return std::endl; }
};
```

but I find that to be a bit too much like boilerplate, so write up some macros that do the job for you:

```
#define RETURNS(X) ->decltype(X) { return (X); } // C++11 lacks non-lambda return value deduction
#define OVERLOAD_SET(F) struct {\
  template<typename... Args>\
  auto operator()(Args&&...args)const\
    RETURNS( F( std::forward<Args>(args)... ) )\
  template<typename T,typename=typename std::enable_if<\
    std::is_same< decltype(static_cast<T>( F )), T >::value\
  >::type>\
  operator T() const { return F; }\
}
static OVERLOAD_SET(std::endl) Endl;
```

then pass `Endl` to your `f`, and calling `Endl(Blah)` ends up doing `std::endl(Blah)`.  Similarly,  assigning `Endl` to a variable, or passing it to a method, does basically the same as assigning `std::endl` to a variable or passing it to a method (wrt overload resolution).

Sadly, the `OVERLOAD_SET` cannot be used within a function, as local types cannot have `template` methods.  If it could be used within a function, then:

```
f(1,2,3, OVERLOAD_SET(std::endl)() );
```

would do what you wanted.  But that would be the language you want to program in, not the language you have.  (Even better would be @Xeo's proposal to allow overload set functors to be automatically generated using some random further abuse of the `[]` syntax, rather than relying on macros).

[Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=59e191f0cf3d46e1e7123a4e52f5e0d0-c59112800dca6ae4674520521ddfe536), where I pass my `endl_functor` to a `print` method and then use `<<` on it without any further ado.

Comment: Note that such a transformed manipulator couldn't be used like a real one anymore: `std::cout << OVERLOAD_SET(std::endl){};` (or even `std::cout << []std::endl;`) will not compile because those two don't produce normal functions, but function objects.

Comment: @xeo `operator T` added and tested!  `endl_functor` now converts to the same things that `std::endl` will convert to.